# Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range...' Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I have a little problem.

I want to filter the DataGrid in Visual Basic 6. I am using this code

> `Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = "columnname like '%" + Me.Txtsearch.Text + "%'"`

All went well. when I put the words "a" in the textbox then, the data that is the letter "a" will appear. But when the letter was removed from the textbox, appears an error like this

> Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another'

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Error message]

Can anyone explain to me why this happens ?

Comment: Since new users join every few minutes, you are probably no longer the newest member on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Have you tried adding an If that checks if the textbox contains a value?

Comment: What do you mean "contains a value"? Sorry i'm beginner :)

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because you not passing any arguments to the filter.
Try putting it as follows:

```
if trim(Me.Txtsearch.Text) <> "" then
    Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = "columnname like '%" + Me.Txtsearch.Text + "%'"
else
    Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = ""
end
```

Comment: I would add an `else` clause that sets `Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = ""` so it clears the filter if the search textbox is empty.

Comment: Ok, Edited @C-Pound Guru.